# Why does adding grouping parentheses cause a regexp to no longer match?

Tags: regular-expressions

If `test-string` is defined like so

```
(setq test-string "fooXbarXbazXextraYstuff")
```

then the regexp `"^[^XY]+X"` matches `test-string`:

```
(string-match "^[^XY]+X" test-string)
=> 0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
```

...but the same regexp with grouping parentheses added no longer matches:

```
(string-match "^\([^XY]+X\)" test-string)
=> nil
```

Simply adorable.

---

Given the behavior above, it is not surprising that

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "^\([^XY]+X\)+" "" test-string)
```

evaluates to the original value of `test-string`.

What regexp must I put in place of the `???` below

```
(replace-regexp-in-string ??? "" test-string)
```

so that the resulting value is the string `"extraYstuff"`?

(BTW, I'd love to know the official/documented rationale for the behavior shown above, if there is one.)

Comment: You need to escape the backslash, when it is inside string literal (as opposed to when you input the regular expression interactively).

Comment: Yes, escaping rules are tricky -- this is why I prefer to use `rx` in my elisp code.

Comment: It's very useful when writing regexps to use `M-x regexp-builder` as it lets you see live how your changes take effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` on your `\(...\)` to read `\\(...\\)`:

```
(string-match "^\\([^XY]+X\\)" "fooXbarXbazXextraYstuff") ; => 0
```

Comment: Oh my god...  Well, thanks & +1.  (I'll accept your answer as soon as ESE lets me.)

Comment: @kjo: I make this mistake with great regularity.

Comment: Instead of bothering with backslash escapes yourself, consider using a tool like [helm-regexp](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Regexp). As the Wiki page notes, it has several advantages, including instant feedback for your regexp on a buffer and a Helm action to add its string form to your kill ring.